# Calculating 'on time performance' between scheduled and actual times

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table of scheduled times for an event and a second of actual times the event happened, for example:

```
Table A
ID    Date         Scheduled
1     2014-09-01   07:05:00
2     2014-09-02   07:05:00
3     2014-09-03   08:05:00
4     2014-09-04   07:10:00

Table B
ID    Date         Actual
1     2014-09-01   07:10:00
2     2014-09-02   07:16:00
3     2014-09-03   08:00:00
4     2014-09-04   14:15:00
```

If we assume that anything within 10 minutes of schedule is considered 'on time', is there a way to return the 'on time performance' using MySQL? In the data set above, the on time performance would be 50%, since two of the events happened within 10 minutes of the schedule.

Supplementary edit: If an event is early, that would also be considered on time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  However, I don't understand why the date and time are in different columns.  You just need to join the two tables together and do some conditional logic:

```
select avg(case when a.date = b.date and a.actual <= a.scheduled + interval 10 minute then 1
                when b.date < a.date then 1
                else 0
           end) as OnTimePerformance
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

This doesn't handle the case where an event is scheduled on one day (say 11:55 p.m.) and the actual time is the next day (12:01 a.m.).  Your data suggests this does not happen.  This condition would be easier if the date and time were in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it

```
select
round((on_time/tot)*100) as performance
from
(
select
count(*) as tot,
sum(
  case when 
    timestampdiff(minute,concat(t1.Date,' ',t1.Scheduled),concat(t2.Date,' ',t2.Actual)) < 10 
  then 1
  end
) as on_time 
from tableA t1
join tableB t2 on t1.id = t2.id
)p;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f29ae/6)**